# Store results including style in vector format for QGIS, ArcGIS

Tags: vector, style

As I am wrapping up my project, I would like to make my results available for download. There are however many flavors to choose from and I was wondering what format is best.

My criteria include:

1. Compatible with QGIS, ArcGIS and GDAL
2. No limitations on length of column names
3. Include a large number of columns (appr. 300)

Nice to have features:
1. Add styling to the file

Exporting to GeoPackage will check most criteria but I am lost on what to do with styling information. The best I can think of is exporting the GeoPackage and include ArcGIS and QGIS project files with relative paths and styling information. Any better ideas?

Comment: GeoPackage can hold style information

Comment: @nmtoken can you specify how or add a URL ?

Answer (score 2):

For QGIS the styles can be saved within the Geopackage as default styles for each layer: open the layer properties, click the 'Style' drop down on the bottom left and 'Save as Default' then 'Datasource Database'. When that layer gets added to any QGIS project it will keep the symbology that you set it to.

As for Arc you could either create a project with symbology set up or else individual lyr files.

I don't know of any single solution which fits both.

Comment: great suggestion. I am exporting my files using python so I will check if I can accomplish (the QGIS part) programmatically.